# When joining 4 Tables with conditions i got the results 3 times

Tags: sql, join, duplicates

i have 4 tables

**word**

```
raw_value
b
t
page_id
```

**page**

```
id
metadata
document_id
```

**document**

```
id
error_status
```

**timing**

```
user_name
to
document_id
```

So here are my four tables, and i want to select the id, the raw_value and the lower(raw_value) but under some conditions, Here is my sql query:

```
SELECT  p.id, 
array_agg(w.raw_value) as words_top ,
array_agg(lower(w.raw_value)) as words_top_lowercase
FROM word w
LEFT OUTER JOIN page p
       ON w.page_id = p.id
       AND ((w.b+w.t)/cast(p.metadata->>'height' as float) < 0.33)
LEFT OUTER JOIN document d
       ON p.document_id = d.id
       AND d.error_status not in ('REVIEW_REQUESTED', 'TO_VALIDATE', 'TO_CORRECT', 'NO_INVOICE')
LEFT OUTER JOIN timing t
       ON d.id = t.document_id
       AND t.user_name IN ('Richard Andrian', 'Adrien Rajon', 'Francine Rak')
       AND t.t0 > '2018-06-15'
group by p.id;
```

I notice that the results is multiplied per 3, for example when i try to look at the "words_top" i got this:

```
 ['Gare', 'Gare', 'Gare', 'La', 'La', 'La', 'Fabrication',
 'Fabrication', 'Fabrication', 'Dépôt', 'Dépôt', 'Dépôt', 'ra', 'ra',
 'ra', 'at', 'at', 'at', ':', 'Télécopie', 'Télécopie', 'Télécopie',
 '0243686300', '0243686300', '0243686300', 'Téléphone', 'Téléphone',
 'Téléphone', 'LAVAL', 'LAVAL', 'LAVAL', '-53000', '-53000', '-53000',
 'Jaurès', 'Jaurès', 'Jaurès', 'Jean', 'Jean', 'Jean', 'Boulevard',
 'Boulevard', 'Boulevard', '39,', '39,', '39,', 'BRICOLAGE',
 'BRICOLAGE', 'BRICOLAGE', '&', '&', '&', 'MATÉRIAUX', 'MATÉRIAUX',
 'MATÉRIAUX', 'Télécopie', 'Télécopie', 'Télécopie', '0299963860',
 '0299963860', '0299963860', ':', ':', ':', ':', 'Téléphone', ':', ':',
 ':', 'Téléphone', 'Téléphone', 'GUERCHE-DE-BRETAGNE',
 'GUERCHE-DE-BRETAGNE', 'GUERCHE-DE-BRETAGNE', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA',
 '-35130', '-35130', '-35130', 'Téléphone', 'Rennes', 'Gedimat',
 'Gedimat', 'Gedimat', '0243060690', '0243060690', '0243060690',
 '0299964442', '0299964442', '0299964442', '0243686301', 'Rennes',
 'de', 'de', 'SOC', 'SOC', 'SOC', 'de', 'Agences', 'Agences',
 'Agences', '0243686301', 'Route', 'Route', 'Route', 'Télécopie',
 'Télécopie', 'Télécopie', '0243091919', '0243091919', '0243091919',
 'Téléphone', 'Téléphone', 'Téléphone', 'CRAON', 'CRAON', 'CRAON',
 '-53400', '-53400', '-53400', 'Pépinière', 'Pépinière', 'Pépinière',
 'La', 'La', 'La', 'ZA', 'ZA', 'ZA', 'Social', 'Social', 'Social',
 'Siège', 'Siège', 'Siège', '0243686301', ':', 'Rennes', '0243091920',
 '0243091920', '0243091920', 'Télécopie', 'Télécopie', 'Télécopie',
 '0243091913', '0243091913', '0243091913', 'S.A.S', 'S.A.S', 'S.A.S',
 'au', 'au', 'au', 'Capital', 'Capital', 'Capital', 'de', 'de', 'de',
 '400768', '400768', '400768', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'Téléphone', 'Téléphone',
 'SELLE-CRAONNAISE', 'SELLE-CRAONNAISE', 'SELLE-CRAONNAISE', 'LA',
 'LA', 'LA', '-53800', '-53800', '-53800']
```

Can you please help me to resolve this problem, i tried to use DISTINCT inside the array_agg but it's not the right way because the words_top for example is supposed to return the word "Téléphone" 4 times, Whereas, the distinct return it only one.  The query i used here return the word "Téléphone" 12 times , it the same for all the other words. This means that all the results are multplied per 3.

When i try to see the list of top_word for a specific page_id and without addin the jointure, i have this kind of result :

> {:,:,:,Siège,Social,ZA,La,Pépinière,-53400,CRAON,Téléphone,0243091919,Télécopie,Route,Agences,de,Rennes,-35130,LA,GUERCHE-DE-BRETAGNE,Téléphone,0299963860,Télécopie,MATÉRIAUX,&,BRICOLAGE,"39,",Boulevard,Jean,Jaurès,-53000,LAVAL,Téléphone,0243686300,Télécopie,at,ra,Dépôt,Fabrication,La,Gare,-53800,LA,SELLE-CRAONNAISE,Téléphone,0243091920,Télécopie,0243091913,S.A.S,au,Capital,de,400768,E,Gedimat,0243060690,0299964442,0243686301,SOC}

I'am looking for this kind of results not a duplicated one.

Comment: Could you add a sample data and better formatted style?
Duplicate records usually came from two things, in fact there is more than one record in one of the tables that you are linking, or it is missing a condition in one of the joins. But is hard to say just looking at this example.

Comment: Try grouping also by `w.raw_value`

Comment: @DDS i try the group by w.raw_value but it still returning the duplicated result

Comment: We had an issue with the float datatype, I see that you are casting into float datatype, try using a decimal

Comment: Maybe `timing` table has the same `document_id` for all three `user_name`?

Comment: @AlexandrKapshuk , I fixed the problem, that's it for evey user_name there is a document_id so this is duplicating the result! Thank you everyone !